# Mounting Drives as user at startup (FSTAB)

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, fstab

I am running Ubuntu and have been having some trouble mounting my 2nd internal HDD.

It would mount with settings made by Disks program but would mount and be owned by root at startup even though I made the directories it was mounting to.

So I went into fstab and at the end of the options list I added `uid=1000,gid=1000` to both partitions I was having trouble with. One ext4 and one fat32

Now at reboot I just get a blank black screen. I believe nofail was an option set by the disks program but I can't log on to check.

What should I do to get my computer to boot again? What should my fstab file look like for a 2nd harddrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from my fstab to mount a 2nd internal drive  (it's a legacy Windows drive, hence the mountpoint name and file system type)

```
UUID=01D0465A0EE56520 /media/Win-G ntfs defaults 0 0
```

Here are the properties for the mount point.  Note that root owns it, but other users have read/write/delete permissions.

[image]

Comment: And your permissions are just permissions of the directory where you mount.

Comment: It means toe order of disk checks. `0` for first and `2` for others.

Comment: No, sorry I mislead you. `0` is disabled. Leave as it is. `1` is for root. For NTFS it should be `0`.

Comment: `2` is used for `ext4` partitions.

Comment: I'm not 100% on what the 2 numbers at the end mean but a reboot and this got me going. I think right now all mine are `0 0` That is fat32 and ext4. is there a good reference or tutorial I should read that explains these?

Comment: There's this: http://superuser.com/questions/247523/fstab-when-do-you-use-the-dump-and-fsck-options but a commenter here said the 2nd field should be 0 for ntfs.  I have 3 extra drives, they are all ntfs and set to 0 0 and they all work fine.